# Google maps v2 mapFragment inside a viewFlipper

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2, viewswitcher, mapfragment

I'm trying to create a mapFragment inside a view flipper. I have tried several approaches to it and cannot get it to work. so far I have tried:

- Declaring the fragment in the right part of the view flipper and accessing it there. The problem with this is that the view isn't loaded until it is switched into so the map doesn't exist and it creates a null pointer error when I try to access it.
- My second approach was declaring a map fragment progromatically and then inserting it into a FrameLayout container using fragment transactions.
- The third thing I tried was loading a fragment from an external file and inserting it into the container using a fragment transaction.

All of these were tried in the `onCreate`and the call that caused them to throw a null pointer exception was inside the `onResume` method. I would appreciate it if anyone has experienced this behavior before and knows how to fix it.

Comment: can you be specific where is problem in code

Comment: The problem is everytime I try to access the googlemap object it is null no matter how or where I try to instansiate it.

Comment: Are you extending `fragmentActivity` ?

Comment: I am, well the roboJuice version of fragment activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As You are extending `FragmentActivity`, indicating that you are trying to use the `Android Support package backport of fragments. However, your element refers to MapFragment, which is for the native`API Level 11` edition of fragments.

Replace MapFragment with SupportMapFragment, and that should clear up this specific crash

```
if that also doesnt solve Then you have a problem with your API key or something. Check LogCat for messages
```

Comment: It was trying to import the support library over the actual API thanks